# find difference between two texts recursive

Tags: python

I am trying to build a recursive function that can identify the different charachters between two strings

```
str1 = "https://google.com"
str2 = "https://goSiogllveer.com"
#expected output = "Silver"
```

example2

```
str1 = 'http://www.wood.com/'
str2 = "http://www.waoBcod.com/"
#expected_output = "aBc"
```

Ideally, I am looking for a recursive solution but any other method is acceptable

Comment: Does the second string always contain more characters than the first? Or can it also be the other way around? So are you looking for str2 - str1 or also str1 - str2?

Comment: Please show your effort towards solving the problem.

Comment: @mbostic either equal or more yes

Answer (score 2):

Try this, whatever is in str1, delete it from str2

```
str1, str2 = list(str1), list(str2)
[str2.remove(i) for i in str1 if i in str2]
print("".join(str2))
```

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the most elegant solution and it is not recursive, but here it is:

```
str1 = 'http://www.wood.com/'
str2 = "http://www.waoBcod.com/"

list1 = list(str1)
list2 = list(str2)

count = 0
diff = []

for c in list2:
    if c == list1[count]:
        count += 1
    else:
        diff.append(c)

diff = "".join(diff)

print(diff)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> str1 = "https://google.com"
>>> str2 = "https://goSiogllveer.com"
>>> list((Counter(list(str2)) - Counter(list(str1))).elements())
['S', 'i', 'l', 'v', 'e', 'r']

>>> "".join(list((Counter(list(str2)) - Counter(list(str1))).elements()))
'Silver'
```

**Edit**:

```
>>> Counter(list(str1))
Counter({'o': 3, 't': 2, '/': 2, 'g': 2, 'h': 1, 'p': 1, 's': 1, ':': 1, 'l': 1, 'e': 1, '.': 1, 'c': 1, 'm': 1})
>>> Counter(list(str2))
Counter({'o': 3, 't': 2, '/': 2, 'g': 2, 'l': 2, 'e': 2, 'h': 1, 'p': 1, 's': 1, ':': 1, 'S': 1, 'i': 1, 'v': 1, 'r': 1, '.': 1, 'c': 1, 'm': 1})
```

Comment: I thought about counting characters but was afraid the order wouldn't stand, can you please explain why this works

Comment: @User19 : You can check by printing counter output. Modified ans for you

Answer (score -1):

This is not a recursive solution because that's not really necessary:

```
str1 = "https://google.com"
str2 = "https://goSiogllveer.com"

s1, s2 = (str1, str2) if len(str1) > len(str2) else (str2, str1)

j = 0
s = ''

for i in range(len(s1)):
    if s1[i] != s2[j]:
        s += s1[i]
    else:
        if (j := j + 1) >= len(s2):
            break

print(s)
```

**Output:**

```
Silver
```